# Ubuntu 18.04 Dell Inspiron 7380 charging issues

Tags: dell, charging

My new Dell 7380 does not charge through USB-type C.
It works just when the PC is off... Is this a known issue on Ubuntu 18.04, or a hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more likely your USB-C charger is not delivering enough current. It seems like the minimum to charge and run via USB-C is 45 watts. You might check to see if the charger you are using is able to deliver at least 45 watts or more, otherwise it could be firmware related - needing a correct updated version?